# prepopulate parent module data and relate module data to the child module on quickcreate SugarCRM 6.5.x

Tags: sugarcrm

I have 3 modules, Let say module A, B are two Parent modules, C is child module(junction) in A and B.
When Quick Create of C from Deatil view of A, on select of the relate module B, need to populate B module data to some other field of C.  and need to pass some data of A to some field of C
(In Detail view of A, C is subpanel and in C a relate field to B). hope I am clear

Im using suagrcrm 6.5.x

can any one help me on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right maybe this helps:

write a view in "modules/YOURMODULE/views.view.subpanelquickcreate.php" and do something like this:

```
require_once('include/EditView/SubpanelQuickCreate.php');
class YOURMODULESubpanelQuickCreate extends SubpanelQuickCreate
{

    function process($module)
    {
        if ($_REQUEST['target_action'] == 'QuickCreate') {
            $this->ev->view = 'QuickCreate';
        }
        $form_name = 'form_Subpanel' . $this->ev->view . '_' . $module;
        $this->ev->formName = $form_name;

        if ($_REQUEST['return_module'] === 'MODULE_A' && isset($_REQUEST['MODULE_A_id'])) {
            $this->prefill($_REQUEST['MODULE_A_id']);
        }
        $this->ev->process(true, $form_name);
        echo $this->ev->display(false, true);
    }

    function prefill($id)
    {
        $modA = new ModA();
        $modA->retrieve($id);
        $this->ev->focus->modA_id = $modA->id;
        $this->ev->focus->modA_name = $modA->name;
        $this->ev->focus->company_name = ...
    }
}
```

Like that when you click on create inside of the subpanel you prefill YOURMODULE with values from the current modules detailview.